# Api C# .Net динамическая ссылка для callback

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

Есть Api которая шлёт запрос другой стороне и в параметре передаёт ссылку на анонимный сервис Api с методом `callbackTest` который что-то делает. Cсылка которая получилась: `https://test.com/api/callbackTest`.

Это работает и всё норм, но я хочу сделать ссылку динамической, то есть `https://test.com/api/callbackTest_Rhfdjr52ffffffdds` и соответственно ссылка которая будет передаваться по другой записи, уже будет другой к примеру такой, `https://test.com/api/callbackTest_RtffgGfF855652dd`, то есть наименование метода + id записи по которой делался запрос.

Можно ли это сделать?

Comment: Если это REST, то надо так `/api/callbackTest/Rhfdjr52ffffffdds` и принимать последний токен как аргумент метода

Comment: @aepot Спасибо! Помогло!